# Ruby on Rails – Models with several many-to-many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, many-to-many, has-many-through

I am currently developing a Dungeons & Dragons 4th Edition Character Sheet application in Ruby on Rails 3.2.1. I am currently at a stage where I realize that I need to associate character races (dwarves, elves, …) with ability bonuses. (Example: a dwarf gets +2 bonuses to the Constitution and Wisdom abilities as a racial trait.)

I currently have the following set up:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base {
  has_many :attributions
  has_many :abilities, through: :attributions
}

class Attribution < ActiveRecord::Base {
  belongs_to :character
  belongs_to :ability

  # The "attributions" table also has the column "score,"
  # which is the character's ability score
}

class Ability < ActiveRecord::Base {
  has_many :attributions
  has_many :characters, through: :attributions
}
```

As you can see, the characters each have their own set of abilities. I figure I may do the same thing for character races, but I am unsure of any best practices in this area.  I could probably use the same join model, creating something like this (`Character` would stay the same, except for an overridden `abilities` method, perhaps):

```
class CharacterRace < ActiveRecord::Base {
  # I am not sure if this will actually work, but I hope
  # you understand what I am trying to do with this
  has_many :racial_ability_traits, class_name: "Attribution"
  has_many :abilities, through: :racial_ability_traits
}

class Attribution < ActiveRecord::Base {
  # The following two are just like before
  belongs_to :character
  belongs_to :ability

  # This field would be new
  belongs_to :character_class
}

class Ability < ActiveRecord::Base {
  # These are the same as above
  has_many :attributions
  has_many :characters, through: :attributions

  # These would be new, and I am not sure if it will work, but
  # I hope you understand what I amm trying to do with this
  has_many :racial_traits, class_name: "Attribution"
  has_many :character_races, through: :racial_ability_traits
}
```

However, even *if* this would work,  I somehow feel like having the same join model for different joins (even if the purpose is pretty much the same) is kind of an ugly approach. I could, of course, create a different kind of join like this:

```
class CharacterRace < ActiveRecord::Base {
  has_many :abilities, through: :attributions

  # These are for the racial bonus
  has_many :racial_ability_bonuses
  has_many :abilities, through: :racial_ability_bonuses
}

class RacialAbilityBonus < ActiveRecord::Base {
  belongs_to :character_race
  belongs_to :ability
}

class Ability < ActiveRecord::Base {
  has_many :attributions
  has_many :abilities, through: :attributions

  # These are for the racial bonus
  has_many :racial_ability_bonuses
  has_many :character_races, through: :racial_ability_bonuses
}
```

This would probably work, but there is a problem. Not only the races can have such traits/bonuses. A magical item might also give an ability bonus. Therefore, an `Item` model should also be given a `has_many :abilities, through: :item_ability_bonus` association. Continuing down the road explained above, this would cause a lot of join models.

I am therefore asking you guys if you know any good approach for handling this problem. Any suggestion about making my existing code better is welcome as well.

I am very thankful for all of your serious answers. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Comment: I remember having read through this before. Thank you for your answer, I will check it out at my earliest opportunity. :-)